# How to implying bagging method for LSTM neural network using pyTorch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

Like the title, my question is how to apply the Bagging method for LSTM using the PyTorch library? I have built one using TensorFlow on python. But now to implied into the system using C and C++, the requirement is I need to using PyTorch?

Is there any recommendation for not need to use the PyTorch and applying directly the model built on tensorflow into real predicting in the system??

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create an ensemble in PyTorch, you can train multiple models separately and then define a class to use them together:

```
class MyEnsemble(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, firstModel, secondModel):
        super(MyEnsemble, self).__init__()
        self.firstModel = modelA
        self.secondModel = modelB
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(in_features, n_classes) #define accordingly
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x1, x2):
        x1 = self.firstModel(x1)
        x2 = self.secondModel(x2)
        x = torch.cat((x1, x2), dim=1)
        x = self.classifier(self.relu(x))
        return x
```

If you want to use your TensorFlow model, there are multiple ways of doing so. One can export it to C++ [Tensorflow -> C++](https://medium.com/@hamedmp/exporting-trained-tensorflow-models-to-c-the-right-way-cf24b609d183)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it seems to lower the accuracy of the model after export it to C++ :(

Comment: When you train the ensemble to learn the last linear layer, how are we sure that we are not training the models as well? Is there a way to ensure that the weights are frozen?

Answer (score 0):

When you create an ensemble in PyTorch, it's better to use the `nn.ModuleList()` class from PyTorch. The `nn.ModuleList()` has the same functions as a normal Python list like `append()`. When you create an Ensemble Model like this, you can directly call the  `backward` operations and the gradient descent will occur through the model.

Below is an ensemble Neural Network (`EnsembleNet`) that uses the `NeuralNet` as individual NN instances for the ensemble.

```
NeuralNet(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_dim, out_dim)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(out_dim, 1)


  def forward(self, X):
    """ X must be of shape [-1, in_dim]"""
    X = self.fc1(X)
    return torch.sigmoid(self.fc2(X))


EnsembleNet(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, net = NeuralNet, num_ensemble=5, seed_val=SEED):
      super(EnsembleNet, self).__init__()
      self.ensembles = nn.ModuleList()

      for i in range(num_ensemble):
          torch.manual_seed(seed_val*i+1)
          if torch.cuda.is_available(): # To randomize init of NNs for Ensembles
              torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed_val*i+1)
          self.ensembles.append(net)

      self.final = nn.Linear(num_ensemble, 1)

  def forward(self, X_in_list):
      pred = torch.cat([net(X_in_list[i]) for i,net in enumerate(self.ensembles)])
      pred = pred.reshape(-1, len(self.ensembles))
      return torch.sigmoid(self.final(pred))
```

To use bagging, simply create an X_input_list where the different elements of the list are Tensors that have been sampled with replacement from your training data. (Your X_input_list and the num_ensemble must be of the same size)

You can modify the `EnsembleNet` initialization code to take a list of different neural networks as well.